# How to encapsulate a .mht file in sharepoint online

Tags: display-template

I have some .mht files and I want to display in a sharepoint page. I'have tried the "content editor" but seems like in only work with HTML files.
There is some solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution would be to not use MTH and use something else, such as a standard SharePoint page or possibly a Wiki.

If I recall, MTH is generally blocked by IE from displaying when the MTH is remote.

Comment: I know but this is not an answer.